# Oracle Apex opening a column link in interactive report?

Tags: javascript, database, oracle, oracle-apex

I have column link in an interactive report. This column link should run an sql query which supposed to return an external URL so I want to open in a new tab/page. How can I do that?

[image]

Somehow with a dynamic action? ..but I cannot make dynamic actions for columns furthermore I should query the data from the table-column.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my point of view, your current column link should **not** run any query. What it should & could do is to call a **function** which returns URL. Something like this:

```
select id,
       name,
       f_url(parameters, go, here) url   --> this
from some_table
where ...
```

---

How to do it?

A *dummy* function; mine returns link to Google. Yours would return something different.

```
create or replace function f_url return varchar2 is
begin
  return 'https://www.google.com';
end;
/
```

In Apex, interactive report's query looks like this; note the `URL` column which *composes* a HTML tag to URL returned by the function I previously created:

```
select deptno, dname, loc, 
  --
  '<a href="' || f_url || '" target="_blank">click here</a>' url
from dept
```

`URL` column's properties:

- type: **plain text** (not a link!)
- escape special characters: No (otherwise, instead of a link you'll see *plain text*)

Run the page; result is

[image]

When you click on "click here", a new tab - with the Google search page - will be opened.

Comment: Thanks! I am not sure if I am able to call a function from a column link. Although it seems to be a good idea. I have the links in the database columns in this way: "https://stackoverflow.com/" so somehow I should also edit them.

Comment: Sorry if my question is stupid but I am quite new to Oracle Apex and I cannot find any simple solution. I submitted a new answer. Thanks for helping!

Comment: I edited my answer and added step-by-step instructions.

Comment: Thank you so much the well detailed instructions! I see you have that 'dummy function' for returning link to Google. In my case the link is stored in a table-column (so each row has a different link) so that's what I should query and display.

Comment: No problem. In function, query that table and return URL stored in a column.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much. Is there any way to connect it with a javascript function which copy the link automatically - so the user will be able to paste it after opening the page?

Comment: You're welcome. As of JavaScript, I'm afraid I'm not good at it, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment my column Link looks like:
[image]

..but this is not the solution because I don't have to open a new Page inside the application. All I want to open the link regarding to an sql query in a new tab/page if the user clicks on it.